# Approximating an equation to an integer

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following integral:

```
Integrate[x^2 + 3*x + 1/3, {x, 0, 10}]
```

> 1460/3

I approached for an integer value:

```
Round[Integrate[x^2 + 3*x + 1/3, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

> 487

I used this value to get a value for **$y$**:

```
NSolve[Integrate[x^2 + 3*x + y, {x, 0, 10}] == 487, y]
```

> {{y -> 0.36666666666666664}}

I tried to use the same concept, but I think it is not correct:

```
NSolve[Integrate[x^2 + 3*x + y, {x, 0, 10}] == Integer, y]
```

What would be the right thing to do?

**EDIT**

I got the result (`y -> 0.36666666666666664`) by the above codes, but I'd like it in a way that I did not need to calculate an integer value to use as a placebo

Comment: What is the question? What equation to you to solve?

Comment: you can choose y to make that integral any integer you like.  `Solve[Integrate[x^2 + 3*x + y, {x, 0, 10}] == 42, y]`

Answer (score 3):

Does this help you?

```
Reduce[Integrate[x^2 + 3*x + y, {x, 0, 10}] == n && 
          n \[Element] Integers, y]

(*     n \[Element] Integers && n \[Element] Integers && 
                     y == 1/30 (-1450 + 3 n)     *)
```

If y should be near 1/3

```
n /. First@Solve[1/3 == 1/30 (-1450 + 3 n), n] // Round

(*    487    *)
```